# How to encode a set of whole numbers $\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$ such that given a number $x$ we can test if $x \in \{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-number-theory

Suppose we have a set of whole numbers $\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$. Is there a way to encode them into a new number $e$ such that we can use $e$ to test if a given number $x \in \{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$? So really I'm looking for two things:

1. Encoding function
   $$f(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)=e$$
2. Test function
   $$p_e(x)=true \iff x \in \{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$$

I'm using this in a computer program so the numbers can't get too big, and it would also be very beneficial to be something that can be implemented to run quickly. Thank you all, cheers.

Comment: Given $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$, you can build a monic polynomial $$p (x) := \prod_{k=1}^n (x - a_k) = c_0 + c_1 x + \cdots + x^n$$ Given a number $b$, if $p (b) = 0$, then $b$ was one of the original $a_k$.

Comment: Sort the integers $a_1<a_2<\dots<a_k$. Then compute $a_1+a_2^2+\dots+a_k^k$. This coding is both space efficient and easily revertible.

Comment: How do I calculate $c_0+c_1+...+c_n$?

Comment: For something like the $5000$ even integers up to $10000$ you could check very quickly. But usually you can do no better than to keep a table of your numbers (which I suppose you could run into one string $a_1xa_2x\cdots$ using one new symbol.) Look up hashing to see how to save space at the expense of some loss of certainty. Think of the case $n=1.$

Comment: Let the a's be indices in the table of primes, and e be the prime product.  The test asks if the prime corresponding to x divides e.  If you have big number arithmetic, this is feasible.  If I were programming it in AWK, and had other uses for the set, I would turn it into a comma delimited string s, split s into an array when needed, and either linear search the array, or create an associative array once where the a's are the keys and 1 is the value.  This is like Aaron Meyerowitz's hashing suggestion, but AWK does the dirty work.  Gerhard "And Numbers Are Strings Too" Paseman, 2017.11.04.

Comment: What about $e=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}2^{a_i}$? You should just check $i$-th bit in the number afterwards. However it is unclear which encoding do you want to get.

Btw you were asking how to calculate $c_0+c_1+\dots+c_n$. It is simply $p(1)=\prod\limits_{k=1}^n (1-a_k)$... :)